# React native: Delete a item from an array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, draggable

I'm trying to remove an item from an array.

Let's say I have an array of 5 items: [0,1,2,3,4]
If I delete item number five [4], it works fine. But if I delete item [1], object [2,3,4] is also deleted. So what am I doing wrong?

This function added a new draggable item

```
  const addshootOutside = index => {
    setShootOutside([
      ...shootOutside,
      <Outside key={index} pageX={positionX} pageY={positionY}/>,
    ]);
  };
```

This function delete a draggable item

```
  const deleteHandler = index => {
    const arr = shootOutside.filter((el, i) => index !== i)
    setShootOutside(arr);
  };
```

Here I call the "deleteHandler"

```
  const twoOptionAlertHandler = () => {
    //function to make two option alert
    Alert.alert(
      //title
      'Ta bort',
      //body
      'Är du säker på att du vill ta bort skott?',
      [
        { text: 'OK', onPress: (index) => deleteHandler(index) },
        {
          text: 'Avbryt',
          onPress: () => console.log('No Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
      //clicking out side of alert will not cancel
    );
  };
```

Here is the my draggable item.

```
  console.log(shootOutside);
  const Outside = () => {
    return (
      <Draggable
        x={200}
        y={200}
        onShortPressRelease={twoOptionAlertHandler}
        renderSize={20}
        renderColor="red"
        renderText="x"
        isCircle
        onDragRelease={e => {
          setPositionY(e.nativeEvent.pageY);
          setPositionX(e.nativeEvent.pageX);
        }}
      />
    );
  };
```

Comment: look into Array.prototype.shift() or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: @Alexander you need to call deleteHandler with an index as parameter

Comment: From the onPress method at Alert.alert ```deleteHandler``` is being called without an index. hence deleting everything in the array

Comment: Mm okey, I updated my code,  but it still doesn't works. How should I get the index?

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander you need to call `deleteHandler` with an index as parameter.

From the `onPress` method at `Alert.alert` in `twoOptionsHandlerAlert` `deleteHandler` is being called without an index. hence deleting everything in the array

I am sure how your app work passing an index as parameter should work fine
For Instance At `Alert.alert` in `twoOptionsHandlerAlert`. Try This:

```
const twoOptionAlertHandler = () => {
//function to make two option alert
Alert.alert(
  //title
  'Ta bort',
  //body
  'Är du säker på att du vill ta bort skott?',
  [
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => deleteHandler(indexToDeleteHere) },
    {
      text: 'Avbryt',
      onPress: () => console.log('No Pressed'),
      style: 'cancel',
    },
  ],
  { cancelable: false }
  //clicking out side of alert will not cancel
);
```

};

Where `indexToDeleteHere` is an index in the array of items to be deleted

Comment: M, thanks for your answer. I feeling so stupid, but how can get the index? I have been try a lot ways, but there is something I doing wrong. I updated my code.

Comment: You are welcome,It depends on how you want the deletion to work. please could you explain a little on how the deletion to work. For instance you take an input from the user and use as index or set a constant value as index which would delete a particular index every time deleteHandler is triggered

Comment: I take a value from the user. When the user presses a button, a draggable object is created with the function (addshootOutside). If the user wants to delete a specific draggable object, the user selects the object and an alert is displayed and where the user confirms his choice. Was it well explained?